# How can I cast datetime to 3 ints (month,year,quarter)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As in the question. How can I convert datetime to 3 integers? For example(04.05.1994) would give me @month=5, @year=1994, @quarter=2. I don't know if it's even possible using CAST and CONVERT functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use `datepart()`:

```
select @month = datepart(month, datecol),
       @year = datepart(year, datecol),
       @quarter = datepart(quarter, datecol)
```

Comment: ...provided fiscal / calendar year align. If your quarters are different then you would need a calculation and/or a calendar table.